# Is the following matrix set a manifold？

Tags: differential-geometry

Given a matrix set $\mathcal{X}=\{X\in\mathbb{R}^{m\times d}: XA^\top=\textbf{0}, A\in\mathbb{R}^{m\times d}\}$, where $A$ is an arbitrary fixed matrix. Then, is $\mathcal{X}$ a submanifold of Riemannian manifold $\mathbb{R}^{m\times d}$?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: Yes, it is. Here's a hint: notice that $\mathcal{X}$ is a linear subspace of $\mathbb{R}^{m\times d}$, and try proving that _any_ linear subspace of $\mathbb{R}^{m\times d}$ is a submanifold.

Comment: Great! Many thanks for your useful answer.